# Scala preserve type parameter of case class object upon copying

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following piece of code

```
class GM
class BM extends GM

case class GenException(message: String) extends RuntimeException(message)  {
     override def toString: String = s"${this.toString()}"
}


case class Hello[T <: GM](t: Try[T])

object Main extends App {
  val first: Hello[BM] = Hello.apply(Success.apply(new BM))
  val second: Hello[Nothing] = first.copy(t = Failure(GenException("hello")))
}
```

As you can see, scala inferred the type of second as `Hello[Nothing]`, but i'd want it to preserve the type the object had on it, i.e. it's a computation failure on type `BM`

Answer (score 2):

Write

```
val second: Hello[BM] = first.copy(t = Failure(GenException("hello")))
```

Scala infers type `Hello[Nothing]` because you write `Hello[Nothing]` explicitly.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
def getTypeTag[T](v: T)(implicit typeTag: TypeTag[T]): TypeTag[T] = typeTag
val second = first.copy(t = Failure(GenException("hello")))
println(getTypeTag(second)) //TypeTag[Hello[Nothing]]

val second: Hello[Nothing] = first.copy(t = Failure(GenException("hello")))
println(getTypeTag(second))//TypeTag[Hello[Nothing]]

val second: Hello[BM] = first.copy(t = Failure(GenException("hello")))
println(getTypeTag(second))//TypeTag[Hello[BM]]
```

Comment: no that was me desugaring scala code. intellij ended up inferring it as `Hello[Nothing]`